# How can I let Mathematica know that the Laplacian of a function is zero?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have a long algebraic expression, and in there somewhere I have derivatives of a function `V[x,y,z]`.

I want to set

```
D[V[x,y,z], {x,2}] + D[V[x,y,z], {y,2}] + D[V[x,y,z], {z,2}]
```

to zero. How can I program this? I don't want to specify the function, I just want to set its Laplacian to zero.

Comment: You need to give an example. Context is important. You can set an expression to zero in number of ways, but it depends on context. You can use replace or use simplify with side relation or any other method. btw, you can just write `Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]` no need to  do it explicitly. Mathematica known the Laplacian. To set equation, do `Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]==0`

Comment: Thanks, A calculation gives an expression like this:

(1/(V[x,y,z]^2))((V^(0,0,1))[x,y,z]^2-(V^(0,1,0))[x,y,z]^2+(V^(1,0,0))[x,y,z]^2
-V[x,y,z] ((V^(0,0,2))[x,y,z]+(V^(0,2,0))[x,y,z]+(V^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]))

The first line is fine. The second line has the Laplacian. I want to teach mathematica to set the second line to zero.

Comment: Are you saying that I can simply try: Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] -> 0

Comment: I can't read what you have there as you did not use the InputForm. It will be better to edit your question and post the input you have, making sure it is in InputForm, and show what output you want after setting the Laplacian to zero. It depends on how complicated the input is, what the solution will be.  It is no different that replacing sayin `Sin[x]` by zero in an expression. But it depends on the input looks like. Trying doing `expr /.Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]->0` and see if that works.

Comment: This is actually a quite interesting problem. Basically what you wants is that the Laplacian generates a differential ideal (in the sense of differential algebra) including all the relations ${\square}=0,\partial{\square}=0,...$, then calculate the quotient image of an expression. I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: The naive approach is to firstly eliminate all the $\partial_{xx},\partial_{xxx},...$-derivatives, then the $\partial_{xxy},\partial_{xxxy},...$-derivatives, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (1/V[x, y, z]^2) Derivative[0, 0, 1][V][x, y, 
     z]^2 - (Derivative[0, 1, 0][V][x, y, z]^2 + 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][V][x, y, z]^2 - 
    V[x, y, z] (Derivative[0, 0, 2][V][x, y, z] + 
       Derivative[0, 2, 0][V][x, y, z] + 
       Derivative[2, 0, 0][V][x, y, z]))
```

[image]

Simplify the expression with the assumption that the [`Laplacian`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Laplacian.html) is zero

```
cons = Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0;

expr2 = Simplify[expr, cons]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Suppose I have not just the Laplacian in the expression, but say, x derivative of the Laplacian.  How will Mathematica know to set the first derivative of the Laplacian to zero too?

Comment: `cons = {Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, D[Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], x] == 0};`